Spring Boot Custom Datasource: How to tell Hibernate to create tables
I was told that if I create Custom Datasource as shown below that Hibernate will no longer automatically recreate Tables since spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is being ignored. How can I configure it to recreate Tables for Custom Datasource?
Full application code can be found at GutHub https://github.com/ivoronline/springboot_db_datasource_create_entitiymanager
application.properties
# ORACLE DB
my.spring.datasource.url      = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/orcl
my.spring.datasource.username = TEST
my.spring.datasource.password = LETMEIN

# HIBERNATE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl       = true
spring.jpa.show-sql           = true


Don't ask the same question again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78831127/spring-boot-table-not-dropped-when-using-custom-entitymanager

How is this the same question. That other question was about why Constructor is not called and you explained that Hibernate Properties are ignored if you use custom Datasource. And then after asking So is it possible for Hibernate to do its usual stuff of creating Tables if I work with Multiple Data sources? You just answered with yes without explaining how. So I posted this question to actually get the answer how to do it.

I did explain it as yo need to manually set the properties on each entitymanagerfactory. And you are now refering to the wrong question, the one marked duplicate is your original question about this topic.

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create works for primary (spring) data source
For using it for another datasource need to create 3 custom bean for set hibernate properties:
@Configuration
public class CustomDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.spring.datasource")
    public DataSource customDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customEntityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("customDataSource") DataSource customDataSource,
            HibernateProperties hibernateProperties) {
        
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(customDataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.stackoverflow.entites"); // Set the package to scan for entities

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Map<String, Object> properties = hibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(
                new HashMap(), new HibernateSettings());

        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create"); // Customize the ddl-auto setting here

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager customTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("customEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory customEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(customEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}


Cannot resolve method 'getProperties' in 'HibernateProperties'

Which version of spring data jpa (spring boot) used ?

I was able to tell Hibernate to create Table if there is none with
hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
But there doesn't seam to be property to drop and create

3.3.2

I was able to do it like this as explained in https://www.thomasvitale.com/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-java-configuration/
  entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

private Properties additionalProperties() {
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
return properties;
}

I edited the answer and it will works fine but that way you tried is fine too but its handy i used the existing properties that parsed by spring itself

OK, thank you. It;s good yo have multiple options.
